# Serialize a list of objects without the parent tag

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a list myListOfItems containing 5 items. All I want to do is to create an xml where all items are displayed like that:

```
<something>
  <someValue/>
</something>

<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>

<somethingElse>
  <someValue/>
</somethingElse>
```

and so far I have this:

```
<something>
    <someValue/>
</something>

<myListOfItems>
  <item>...</item>
  <item>...</item>
  <item>...</item>
  <item>...</item>
  <item>...</item>
</myListOfItems>

<somethingElse>
  <someValue />
</somethingElse>
```

And this is how I do it:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=34)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("passengerDetails", IsNullable=false)]
public List<Item> myListOfItems {
    get {
        return this.myListOfItemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.myListOfItemsField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("myListOfItems");
    }
}
```

How can I do so the parent myListOfItems tag is omitted?

Edit:
As for the topics you mentioned:
If I change the XmlArrayItemAttribute to XmlElement I get this

> InvalidOperationException: XmlElement, XmlText, and XmlAnyElement cannot be used in conjunction with XmlAttribute, XmlAnyAttribute, XmlArray, or XmlArrayItem.

And when I comment out the XmlArrayAttribute portion I get this

> InvalidOperationException: Inconsistent sequencing: if used on one of the class's members, the 'Order' property is required on all particle-like members, please explicitly set 'Order' using XmlElement, XmlAnyElement or XmlArray custom attribute on class member 'item'.

Now how can I set order for multiple items?

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use serialize.  Instead use xml linq :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;


namespace ConsoleApplication73
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<string> items = doc.Descendants("item").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();

        }

    }

}
```